# Centering with Align and Tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, align, tcolorbox

I'm not very experienced with using beamer yet and am running into a recurrent problem with using textcolorbox and align together in a frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}


\newcommand\FontSmall{\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools} % coloneqq
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}

\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\bigK}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\bigL}{\mathbb{L}}
\newcommand{\bigU}{\mathbb{U}}
\newcommand{\bigV}{\mathbb{V}}


\begin{document}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Separation of mean and covariance steering}
\FontSmall

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue!10!black,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,right=2pt]
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\begin{align*}
J(U,V) &= \E[X^\intercal\bar{Q}X + U^\intercal \bar{R} U - V^\intercal \bar{S} V] \\
X &= \A x_0 + \B U + \C V + \D W
\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,top=5pt,bottom=0pt,right=2pt]
Unconstrained Mean Steering Game (UMSG)
\begin{align}
    &\textrm{Payoff Function}: J_{\mu}(\bar{U},\bar{V}), \nonumber\\
    &\textrm{where}\quad \bar{X} = \A\mu_0 + \B\bar{U} + \C\bar{V}, \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.52\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,right=2pt]
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\begin{align*}
J_{\mu}(\bar{U},\bar{V}) &= \bar{X}^\intercal\bar{Q}\bar{X} + \bar{U}^\intercal \bar{R} \bar{U} - \bar{V}^\intercal\bar{S}\bar{V} \\
\bar{X} := \E[X] &= \A \mu_0 + \B \bar{U} + \C\bar{V}
\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,right=2pt]
\begin{align*}
\hspace*{-3cm}
J_{\Sigma}(\tilde{U},\tilde{V}) &= \textrm{tr}(\bar{Q}\Sigma_{XX}) + \textrm{tr}(\bar{R}\Sigma_{UU}) - \textrm{tr}(\bar{S}\Sigma_{VV}) \\
\tilde{X} := X - &\E[X] = \A \tilde{x}_0 + \B \tilde{U} + \C\tilde{V} + \D W
\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\vspace{0.6cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,top=5pt,bottom=0pt,right=0pt]
Unconstrained Covariance Steering Game (CCSG)
\begin{align*}
    &\textrm{Payoff Function}: J_{\Sigma}(\tilde{U},\tilde{V}), \nonumber\\
    &\textrm{where}\quad \tilde{X} = \A \tilde{x}_0 + \B \tilde{U} + \C\tilde{V} + \D W, \nonumber
\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

My goal is simply to have these two columns with each block of text centered in the shaded box. It seems simple enough, but I keep running into problems. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Adding `left=2pt` for an even left and right margin should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `halign=center` in tcolorboxes which contain text and maths and in boxes with only math I think it's easier to use `ams gather*` option to center every equation. With `ams gather*` or other math environment options, you avoid to write them inside the box (see pages 367-370 in tcolorbox documentation)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\newcommand\FontSmall{\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools} % coloneqq
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}

\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\bigK}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\bigL}{\mathbb{L}}
\newcommand{\bigU}{\mathbb{U}}
\newcommand{\bigV}{\mathbb{V}}


\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    before skip=10pt,
    after skip=10pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    left=1pt,
    right=1pt,
    halign=center,
    #1
}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style={colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!75!black}}
    

\begin{document}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Separation of mean and covariance steering}
\FontSmall

\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.47\textwidth}
\begin{mybox}[mystyle=blue]
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\begin{align*}
J(U,V) &= \E[X^\intercal\bar{Q}X + U^\intercal \bar{R} U - V^\intercal \bar{S} V] \\
X &= \A x_0 + \B U + \C V + \D W
\end{align*}
\end{mybox}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{mybox}[mystyle=blue]
Unconstrained Mean Steering Game (UMSG)
\begin{align}
    &\textrm{Payoff Function}: J_{\mu}(\bar{U},\bar{V}), \nonumber\\
    &\textrm{where}\quad \bar{X} = \A\mu_0 + \B\bar{U} + \C\bar{V}, \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{mybox}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.53\textwidth}
\begin{mybox}[mystyle=blue, ams gather*]
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
J_{\mu}(\bar{U},\bar{V}) = \bar{X}^\intercal\bar{Q}\bar{X} + \bar{U}^\intercal \bar{R} \bar{U} - \bar{V}^\intercal\bar{S}\bar{V} \\
\bar{X} := \E[X] = \A \mu_0 + \B \bar{U} + \C\bar{V}
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[mystyle=red, ams gather*]
J_{\Sigma}(\tilde{U},\tilde{V}) = \textrm{tr}(\bar{Q}\Sigma_{XX}) + \textrm{tr}(\bar{R}\Sigma_{UU}) - \textrm{tr}(\bar{S}\Sigma_{VV}) \\
\tilde{X} := X - \E[X] = \A \tilde{x}_0 + \B \tilde{U} + \C\tilde{V} + \D W
\end{mybox}
\vspace{0.6cm}
\begin{mybox}[mystyle=red]
Unconstrained Covariance Steering Game (CCSG)
\begin{align*}
    &\textrm{Payoff Function}: J_{\Sigma}(\tilde{U},\tilde{V}), \nonumber\\
    &\textrm{where}\quad \tilde{X} = \A \tilde{x}_0 + \B \tilde{U} + \C\tilde{V} + \D W, \nonumber
\end{align*}
\end{mybox}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the following MWE, I defined a new tcolorbox in order to avoid haivng to repeat the margin settings over and over. I also added `left=2pt` in order to horizontally center the contents in each box. The contents of the second box in the right column are still wider than the box widh. You will therefore have to adjust the spacing there.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}


\newcommand\FontSmall{\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools} % coloneqq
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}

\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\bigK}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\bigL}{\mathbb{L}}
\newcommand{\bigU}{\mathbb{U}}
\newcommand{\bigV}{\mathbb{V}}

\colorlet{MyBoxGray}{blue!10!black}
\colorlet{MyBoxLightGray}{black!5!white}

\colorlet{MyBoxBlue}{blue!75!black}
\colorlet{MyBoxLightBlue}{blue!5!white}

\colorlet{MyBoxRed}{red!75!black}
\colorlet{MyBoxLightRed}{red!5!white}


\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][MyBoxLightGray]{colback=#1,% first argument determines box' background color, optional, if not given, MyBoxLightGray is used 
                                        colframe=#2,% second argument determines frame color, mandatory argument
                                        before skip=10pt,
                                        after skip=10pt,
                                        top=0pt,
                                        bottom=0pt,
                                        right=2pt,
                                        left=2pt
                                        }




\begin{document}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Separation of mean and covariance steering}
\FontSmall

\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{mybox}{MyBoxGray}
      \abovedisplayskip=0pt
      \belowdisplayskip=0pt
      \begin{align*}
        J(U,V) &= \E[X^\intercal\bar{Q}X + U^\intercal \bar{R} U - V^\intercal \bar{S} V] \\
        X &= \A x_0 + \B U + \C V + \D W
      \end{align*}
    \end{mybox}
    \vspace{2cm}
    \begin{mybox}[MyBoxLightBlue]{MyBoxBlue}
      Unconstrained Mean Steering Game (UMSG)
      \begin{align}
        &\textrm{Payoff Function}: J_{\mu}(\bar{U},\bar{V}), \nonumber\\
        &\textrm{where}\quad \bar{X} = \A\mu_0 + \B\bar{U} + \C\bar{V}, \nonumber
      \end{align}
    \end{mybox}
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}{0.52\textwidth}
    \begin{mybox}[MyBoxLightBlue]{MyBoxBlue}
      \abovedisplayskip=0pt
      \belowdisplayskip=0pt
      \begin{align*}
        J_{\mu}(\bar{U},\bar{V}) &= \bar{X}^\intercal\bar{Q}\bar{X} + \bar{U}^\intercal \bar{R} \bar{U} - \bar{V}^\intercal\bar{S}\bar{V} \\
        \bar{X} := \E[X] &= \A \mu_0 + \B \bar{U} + \C\bar{V}
      \end{align*}
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}[MyBoxLightRed]{MyBoxRed}
      \begin{align*}
        J_{\Sigma}(\tilde{U},\tilde{V}) &= \textrm{tr}(\bar{Q}\Sigma_{XX}) + \textrm{tr}(\bar{R}\Sigma_{UU}) - \textrm{tr}(\bar{S}\Sigma_{VV}) \\
        \tilde{X} := X - &\E[X] = \A \tilde{x}_0 + \B \tilde{U} + \C\tilde{V} + \D W
      \end{align*}
    \end{mybox}
    \vspace{0.6cm}
    \begin{mybox}[MyBoxLightRed]{MyBoxRed}
      Unconstrained Covariance Steering Game (CCSG)
      \begin{align*}
        &\textrm{Payoff Function}: J_{\Sigma}(\tilde{U},\tilde{V}), \nonumber\\
        &\textrm{where}\quad \tilde{X} = \A \tilde{x}_0 + \B \tilde{U} + \C\tilde{V} + \D W, \nonumber
      \end{align*}
    \end{mybox}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```